# Stop Listener after first update

Tags: android, listener

I want to know the signal strength of my current cell tower on Android. After some research I found, that I should use a `PhoneStateListener` which listen for an update to get the value (strange way to do that IMHO).

So I want to get the signal as soon as I get it and stop the listener after. This is the code I use :

```
// object containing the information about the cell
MyGSMCell myGSMCell = new MyGSMCell(cid,lac);
// object listening for the signal strength
new GetGsmSignalStrength(myGSMCell, context);

...

public class GetGsmSignalStrength {

    private MyGSMCell callback;
    private TelephonyManager telMan;
    private MyPhoneStateListener myListener;

    public GetGsmSignalStrength(MyGSMCell callback, Context context) {
            this.callback = callback;
            this.myListener = new MyPhoneStateListener();
            this.telMan = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
            this.telMan.listen(this.myListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_SIGNAL_STRENGTHS);

    }

    private class MyPhoneStateListener extends PhoneStateListener
    {
            public void onSignalStrengthsChanged(SignalStrength signalStrength)
            {
                    // get the strength  
                    super.onSignalStrengthsChanged(signalStrength);
                    // return it to the MyGSMCell object to set the value
                    callback.setStrength(signalStrength.getGsmSignalStrength());
            }
    }
}
```

I would like to stop the listener as soon as I send a `setStrength(value)`

Any idea ?

Thank you

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#listen%28android.telephony.PhoneStateListener,%20int%29):

> To unregister a listener, pass the listener object and set the events
>   argument to LISTEN_NONE (0).

So, add this to your listener:

```
telMan.listen(myListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_NONE);
```